# Perl Thread Safe Modules

Tags: multithreading, perl, module

I am trying to take a Perl program I wrote and thread it.  The problem is I read that some modules aren't "thread safe".  How do I know if a module is thread safe?  I've looked around for a list and cannot locate one.

To test out one module I use frequently (Text::CSV_XS) I tried the following code out:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
require Text::CSV_XS;

my $CSV = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, eol => "\n" }) or die("Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag());
open my $OUTPUT , ">:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die("test.csv: $!");

share($CSV);

my $thr1 = threads->create(\&sayHello('1'));
my $thr2 = threads->create(\&sayHello('2'));
my $thr3 = threads->create(\&sayHello('3'));


sub sayHello
{
 my($num) = @_;

 print("Hello thread number: $num\n");

 my @row = ($num); 
  lock($CSV);{
   $CSV->print($OUTPUT, \@row);
   $OUTPUT->autoflush(1);
  }#lock
}#sayHello
```

The output I receive is the following:

```
Hello thread number: 1
Segmentation fault
```

Does this mean the module is not thread safe, or is it another problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try to come up with the smallest program you can that causes the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Generally speaking, core and high-visibility modules *are* thread-safe unless their documentation says otherwise.

That said, there are a few missteps in your post:

1. `share($CSV)`
   This clears `$CSV` (a blessed hashref), [just as documented in `threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html#BUGS-AND-LIMITATIONS). Generally, you want to share() complex objects *prior* to initialization or, perhaps in this case, share() some dumb `$lock` variable between threads.
   Since `$CSV` holds state for the underlying XS, this might lead to undefined behavior.
   *But this isn't your segfault.*
2. `threads->create(\&sayHello('1'));`
   You are mistakenly invoking `sayHello(1)` in the main thread and passing *a reference to its return value* to `threads->create()` as a (bogus) start routine.
   You meant to say:

   ```
   threads->create(\&sayHello, '1');
   ```

   *But this isn't your segfault.*

   (**EDIT** Just to clarify -- a bad start routine here doesn't risk a SEGV in any case.  `threads::create` properly complains if an unrecognized subroutine name or non-CODE ref is passed in.  In your case, however, you are segfaulting too quickly to reach this error handling.)
3. Encodings are not thread-safe.
   Again [as documented in `encodings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/encoding.html#KNOWN-PROBLEMS), the `encoding` module is not thread-safe.
   Here's the smallest possible code I could get to reproduce your symptoms:

   ```
   use threads;
   open my $OUTPUT , ">:encoding(utf8)", "/dev/null" or die $!;
   threads->create( sub {} )->join;
   ```

   That's perl 5.12.1 with threads-1.77 on i686-linux-thread-multi, if you're interested.  Drop the "utf8" magic, and it works just fine.

   *This is your segfault*

Comment: This saved me hours of searching for the cause of my segfault. Thanks!